# Record All Traffic Hitting Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, logging

I have a`Netgear WNDR4300` router.  I was curious if there was an option to see all websites that are accessed from any device hitting the router.  I have set-up an `OpenDNS` affiliation, but it seems to be missing a few sites that are accessed.  Are there alternatives or more descriptive ways of logging such info?

Comment: You'd likely need a proxy server and a log analyzer or something to capture and sniff all the traffic if the router doesn't have such a built in feature, and you know for sure your OpenDNS logs are not capturing everything you need. You say it seems you are missing a few sites that are accessed with OpenDNS so I assume this means YOU accessed a site and then couldn't find applicable logs or something along those lines where you know a site, etc. was visited but you couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw DDWRt on it "as explained in one of the other answers". and you can add [Yamon](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=955030) Network monitor. This is for in depth and real time tracking you can see what bandwidth is used per device. I use it in my home and it helps a lot with keeping up with the data usage each month or finding certain ips im looking for.

Here is the document to help you get setup if you wish to go this route. [document](http://www.mediafire.com/view/b488czq0xg242cg/Tutorial_on_configuring_YAMON_network_monitor_on_usb.docx)

This allows a web interface where you can keep track and export data. All you need is the router flashed and a usb drive setup with the script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `4300` firmware is similar to the `3800`:

```
[site allowed: somesite.com] from source 192.168.2.7, Monday, January 18,2016 22:59:01
[site allowed: somesite.com] from source 192.168.2.7, Monday, January 18,2016 22:59:01
[site allowed: somesite.com:8080] from source 192.168.2.220, Monday, January 18,2016 22:59:01
[site allowed: somesite.com] from source 192.168.2.7, Monday, January 18,2016 22:59:00
[site allowed: somesite.com] from source 192.168.2.7, Monday, January 18,2016 22:59:00
[site allowed: somesite.com] from source 192.168.2.7, Monday, January 18,2016 22:59:00
[site allowed: somesite.com] from source 192.168.2.7, Monday, January 18,2016 22:59:00
```

This was done with the keyword/domain blocking feature. If you turn it on but dont actually block anything then it just logs all that its doing. You'll then want to email logs when full as they'll fill up fast.

Comment: Is this a feature in the router itself?

Comment: @user2676140 Yep.

Answer (score 1):

Throw [DD-Wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Netgear) onto the router, add [Wireshark](https://www.question-defense.com/2010/02/04/use-wireshark-and-dd-wrt-router-firmware-to-imitate-port-monitoring-on-a-router-switch-port) to a box on your network and redirect traffic to it.  Alternatively, use TCPDump on the router itself to monitor traffc in-depth.